# background.ts shows an error "Service worker registraion failed" but when i change it backgrounds.js it works fine in manifest.json

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

When i try to register background.js as service worker with the following code it works fine.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.action.setBadgeText({
      text: "OFF",
    });
  });
```

But when i try to do the same with .ts file it show's me this error
[image: The Error]

Here's my manifest.json file

```
"background": {
"service_worker": "background.ts",
"type": "module"
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between a .js and a .ts file?

Comment: - umm.... yes .ts (typescript) is a language built on javascript
- which is strongly typed and provides helpful intellisence(better than orginal js)
- Tt also points out silly mistakes while development 
            like trying to access an object porperty which doesn't exist 
- whereas javascript would only show the error on the runtime or build time
IS THERE MORE TO IT THAN THIS? IF YES PLZ HELP!! I'm confused as hell right now

Comment: Uuuuuuuuuuuhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhmmmmmmmmmmm - Your `manifest.json` contains the line `"service_worker": "background.ts",` which tells Chrome to load a .ts file when the extension is installed (when you install an extension in Chrome, the first thing Chrome does is read `manifest.json`). But Chrome doesn't speak Typescript. That's not a problem because Typescript gets transpiled into Javascript. So you either need to write `"service_worker": "background.js",` in `manifest.json`. Or you need to configure your Typescript compiler to replace the `.ts` in `manifest.json` with `.js`.

Comment: Thanks i just changed it to .js and compiled before loading and it worked